# Avoid complex joins in SSRS 2008-r2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report i need to create that has a severe performance problem.
I need to create a catalogue of all courses in our database.
Here is the simplified data model:

Organizational Unit --> contains multiple Courses --> which contains Multiple Activities;
Each activity contains the following:

- A list of attached links
- A list of prerequisite activities
- A list of additional property - value pairs (Cataloging information)
- A list of required resource types and quantity for each resource type
- A list of Training Objectives

and I wish to create a report that will group everything to look something like that:[image]

After creating the straightforward query which joins all tables together i got almost 6 million rows because of different cartesian products that occur due to joining the activities table with all the 1-many relation table for getting the attached links resources etc...

I was thinking to avoid that in several ways:

1. sub reports that will list the different lists of items foreach activity.
2. create an XML field foreach of the described above lists and parse it using VB in my report
3. use multiple datasets in the report and somehow use lookup functions to list the different values.

Results so far:

1. sub-report proved to be very inefficient with regards to performance and it took 50% more that what it took with the original 6 million row query.
2. the xml fields are very efficent DB-wise but it will be trouble to format the data using VB i would very much like to avoid that if possible,
3. I cannot seem to find the right way to use lookupSet to get a list of attachment names and their links next to them.

**so my questions are:**

1. what is the best practice when displaying an entity with a lot of 1-many relations that need to be displayed when dealing with a lot of data and SSRS 2008-r2.
2. is there a way to join data using lookup function and somehow create "nested tables" that will list 1-many relations
3. any other suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the best possible JOINs for your query? INNER JOINs are preferred, LEFT and RIGHT OUTER next. Avoid FULL OUTER JOINs. What you are describing sounds like a need for query optimization, not changes to the report. There are 'lookup' approaches for SSRS, but SQL is often better at working with this set-based data.

Comment: The query is truly doomed .. as i have to join all tables that represent additional data for each activity and that will multiple each row by `activity * number of objectives * number of resource requirements * number of additional properties * number of attachments * number of prerequisites` so this is what i want to avoid getting into.. any way you try this it will end bad :)

Comment: Report Warehouse if I ever heard of it.  Generally when I get queries that are going to be this intense and you have to have the data, there are a few things to consider.  1. Can you dump the data periodically to a location in another place?  2. Can you index the heck out of that location instead.  Most of the reporting I do daily is incremental captures from production at 4:00 AM that is a difference of the last day.  The problem seesm to lie with collection and presentation not SSRS.  You would get similar problems with any reporting strategy I would guess.

Comment: In a similar problem i have noticed that returning an XML string in one of the fields representing one of the collection actually made the query significantly faster as i had to return significantly less rows and used up less memory. i will try the same approach later today with this query and let you know about the progress...

Comment: Have you got anything working? If so how long does it take?

Comment: I got something that now works for 40 seconds using sub queries and for xml. but now i need to write custom code that transforms that xml to something readable... :(

Comment: 40 seconds is decent! You should ask another question...

Comment: Also, i think you should post your own answer and mark it. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a drill down report? This looks like a good option to have activities listed and the courses being summarized and then drillable with the detail separated, or similar.

Or you can cache your report if the data change is unimportant?

6m records is a lot for a ssrs report!